# I am unable to install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processor

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, visualization

I am unable to install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processor no matter what I try.

I have enabled virtualization in AVAST and BIOS:

[image: 1]

I have disabled Hyper-V:

[image: 2]

This is the error I get:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. After enabling the virtualization and disabling Hyper-V, I reinstall it.

Comment: what did you reinstall?